# Firebase Authentication in iOS with latest update to Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

We have recently updated our app to Swift 5 and it seems to have stopped Firebase authentication working for new user sign-ups. The are presented with an error message 'whoops, something went wrong'.

The weird thing is we've a test number and verification code and it can get through fine on a device that has already had the app installed previously but have deleted and re-installed. On a completely new device that has never had the app installed it doesn't work.

How could this be possible and any suggestions what might be going wrong - assuming it is an app side issue rather than the Firebase API etc.

Thanks,

Ali

Comment: post code, stacktrace and screenshots

Comment: Try updating the pods... Hopefully that would work

Comment: Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this super important and very relevant post on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)